# How to change dc charts based on a value from a dropdown menu?

Tags: jquery, ajax, dc.js

I am trying to create charts with dc.js based on selected dropdown menu value.

So if a user select TYPE A from the dropdown menu, chart1, chart2, chart3, chart4, chart5 will display and if he or she select TYPE B, chart1, chart2, chart6, chart7 and chart8 will display.  All charts are using the same data.

I tried with Ajax call but all charts are not display.

Comment: That sounds like the right approach. There's nothing unique about dc.js in this regard - you can create `div`s dynamically and initialize them as charts on the fly. Are there errors displayed in the browser console? If you are able to post a fiddle we may be able to help troubleshoot.